# SimpleXMLElement foreach only shows when there is more than one result

Tags: php, simplexml

I have a simple http request.

Works great, providing there is more than 1 result.

The result comes back as an xml file which I then put into a table for the end user to see.

How do I make the foreach work when there is only one result?

```
$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
  echo "There are no Jobs available ";
} else {
?>

<table id ="table-job" class="container sortable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
<th class="job" > Job</th>
 <th class="position" > position</th>
 <th class="name" > Name</th>
</tr>
</thead>


<?php
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($response);

foreach($xml->record as $item)
?>
<tr>
<td class="jon"><?php echo (string)$item->job; ?></td>
<td class="position"><?php echo (string)$item->position; ?></td>
<td class="name"><?php echo (string)$item->name; ?></td>
</tr>
```

When there is more than one result sent back in response, it works fine.

If there is nothing then it will say There are no Jobs available

Which is expected.

However if there is only 1 result then nothing is showing, Its as though the foreach just does not work.

Comment: Hi, please can you [edit] this question to remove the parts that are not relevant (the HTML, and the curl calls) and include a sample of XML that reproduces the problem. Also make sure the PHP code you've shown us is something you've actually run and seen the result described. This should give us a [mcve] so we can help with your problem, rather than just guessing.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You just look at the following code. I hope it's work for you.

```
 <?php
 $xml = simplexml_load_file("sample.xml", NULL, LIBXML_NOCDATA);

 foreach ($xml->record as $item) {?>
 <tr>
    <td class="jon"><?php echo (string)$item->job; ?></td>
    <td class="position"><?php echo (string)$item->position; ?></td>
    <td class="name"><?php echo (string)$item->name; ?></td>
 </tr>
 <?php } ?>
```

Comment: Could you add an explanation of what you've changed here? The only difference I can see is the inclusion of `LIBXML_NOCDATA`, which makes no difference to the output, because `(string)` always gives the value of CDATA nodes anyway.